# Recursive query in Oracle - length of chain

Tags: sql, database, oracle, recursion

i've got table with some posts. Post have fields: `post_id (key)` and `parent_post_id (can be null).`
( If post `A` is replying to post `B` then `A.parent_post_id = B.post_id`).
My problem is: write query to oracle db to get 'chain length' for every post. I mean: for every post_id i want to know how many nested child there are.(So it's more like tree size, but chain example would be helpful too)
I have tried some recursive queries but i this case i helpless.

Fe. if arrow ( `<-`) means is parent. For `A <- B <- C <- D` I want to get:

```
A 3
B 2
C 1
D 0
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried?  Are you using CONNECT BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical queries are made for your case.
I slightly extended your tree in the following way:

```
A <- B <- C  <- D
     B <- C1 <- D1 
          C1 <- D2
```

If I understand you correctly, the following are the desired results:

```
A   6
B   5
C   1
C1  2
D   0
D1  0
D2  0
```

Here is the query:

```
with source_data as (
  select 'A' post_id, null parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'B' post_id, 'A' parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'C' post_id, 'B' parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'D' post_id, 'C' parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'C1' post_id, 'B' parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'D1' post_id, 'C1' parent_post_id from dual
  union
  select 'D2' post_id, 'C1' parent_post_id from dual
),
chains as (
  select connect_by_root post_id post_id, post_id child_post_id
  from source_data
  connect by nocycle prior post_id = parent_post_id
)
select post_id, count(1) - 1 chain_length
from   chains
group by post_id
order by 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are after Oracle [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

```
WITH posts AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS post_id, null as parent_post_id FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'B' AS post_id, 'A' as parent_post_id FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'C' AS post_id, 'B' as parent_post_id FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'D' AS post_id, 'C' as parent_post_id FROM DUAL
)
SELECT post_id, level AS chain_length
  FROM posts
 START WITH parent_post_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR post_id = parent_post_id;
```

You can make the tree more complex such as adding a `B2` reply to post `A` to see larger variety of data representation as you would see in the real world.

In my example I made the starting point `A` whereas you had it `D` feel free to change as you like. I also started from 1 you can make it `level - 1` if you want to have a zero based index.